# List json expendable child not accurate

Tags: android, json

This is my `JSON` file,

```
  [{
    "Title": "AY",
    "Items": [{
        "Name": "Alex",
        "RoadNameShort": "AY"
    }, {
        "Name": "Kep",
        "RoadNameShort": "AY"
    }, {
        "Name": "Lower",
        "RoadNameShort": "AY"
    }]
  }, {
    "Title": "BK",
    "Items": [{
        "Name": "Chantek",
        "RoadNameShort": "BK"
    }, {
        "Name": "Wood",
        "RoadNameShort": "BK"
    }]
  }]
```

This is my Java Code,

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataHeade = new ArrayList<String>();

listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

// Adding child data for lease offer
List<String> lease_offer = new ArrayList<String>();


JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonstr);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    // tmp hash map for single contact
    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
    listDataHeader.add(c.getString("Title"));
    String title = c.getString("Title");

    JSONArray items = c.getJSONArray("Items");
    for (j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(j);
        String name = item.getString("Name");
        Log.d("email", name);

        listDataHeade.add(item.getString("Name"));

        lease_offer.add(item.getString("Name"));
        // Header into Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), lease_offer);
    }
}
```

For parent I used `Title`. Child is `Name`. I got correctly for group which is title AY, BK. But my problem is for child. Names Chantek and wood should be under group BK, not in group AY. But in group AY, I also get Chantek and wood be as child.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `listDataChild` outside inner loop because you need to add all child to parent list after iterate all childs and initialise `lease_offer` before inside loop start because each parent need to create new child list as below :

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonstr);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    // tmp hash map for single contact
    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = c.getString("Title");
    listDataHeader.add(title);

    JSONArray items = c.getJSONArray("Items");
    / Adding child data for lease offer
    List<String> lease_offer = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (j = 0; j < items.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(j);
        String name = item.getString("Name");
        Log.d("email", name);
        listDataHeade.add(name);
        lease_offer.add(name);
    }
    // Header into Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), lease_offer);
}
```

Comment: The result still same... child for group BK also include in group AY